# Step by step on how to perform tahajjud prayer

Tags: salat, tahajjud

Is it as simple as 2 raka'at x 4 which is a total of 8 raka'at or is it different 
Also what are the surahs that are recited

Answer (score 1):

**Tahajjud (Night prayer)**

It is a voluntary prayer and a best way to purify the soul.
Tahajjud Prayer does not entail a specific number of rak`ahs that must be performed.

Moreover, performing Tahajjud prayers regularly qualifies one as one of the righteous and helps one earn God's bounty and mercy.

God says :

> And from [part of] the night, pray with it as additional [worship] for
>   you; 
>   it is expected that your Lord will resurrect you to a praised station.(isra,79)

see [3:17](http://quran.com/3/17), [25:64](http://quran.com/25/64), [32:16](http://quran.com/32/16), [33:35](http://quran.com/33/35), [39:9](http://quran.com/39/9), [51:17-18](http://quran.com/51/17-18), [73:1-4](http://quran.com/73/1-4), [73:20](http://quran.com/73/20)

**Number of rakaats and time**

I practice tahajjud prayer starting with two rakat followed by two rakat and (so on) and finish with one rakat. I usually recite the surahs, the one i know its translation too (yusuf,isra,yunus..etc). The time i pray usually between (3:30-fajr).